# Where am i doing a mistake in the for loop statement?

Tags: c, for-loop

This is my program with one `for` loop:

```
int main() 
{
   int prod, i, num;

   printf("\nHOW MANY NUMBERS WOULD YOU LIKE ME TO MULTIPLY\n");
   scanf("%d", &num);

   prod = 1;

   for (i = 0;  i <= num;  i++)
   {
       prod = prod * i;
   }

   printf("\nTHE FACTORIAL OF THE GIVEN %d NUMBERS IS %d \n", num, prod);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

When I execute the program it gives me `0` as the output even when i input the `num` value as 5 or any other number the for loop is not does not increment .  Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: What's the value of `i` in the first pass through the loop?

Comment: Yes. What is the value of `prod` after the multiplication with `i`? You shouldn't start your loop with 0, but with 1.

Comment: Are you aware that 0! == 1?

Comment: after first pass it is 0 that fine but when i want it to increment it and multiply it untill the value of i is <= num even then i am getting 0

Comment: As M Oehm said, think what happens. You won't ever get anything else than 0 when multiplying with the initial 0.

Comment: A product is zero if any of its factors are zero. You have thoughtfully initialised `prod` to one, but then make it zero in the first pass through the loop. Fixing that will automatically give you 0! = 1, as Weather vane pointed out.

Comment: thanks this is a silly mistake so i am going to remove the question im sorry for not trying to think

Comment: That's some high level math right there ..

Answer (score 3):

You are multiplying everything by `0`. After the first loop, `prod` is `0`. Then you use that to multiply by the next value of `i`. Zero times any number is zero.

You can fix this by iterating in the range [1, num] thus:

```
for (i = 1;  i <= num;  i++)
{
    prod *= i; /* same effect as prod = prod * i */
}
```

Comment: thanks this is a silly mistake so i am going to remove the question im sorry for not trying to think

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is the loop

```
for (i = 0;  i <= num;  i++)
```

As you multiply by `i` this will always give a product 0.

You should have

```
for (i = 1;  i <= num;  i++)
```

Comment: thanks this is a silly mistake so i am going to remove the question im sorry for not trying to think

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0;  i <= num;  i++)
{
   prod = prod * i;
}
```

In this loop at first iteration `i=0` , and due to `prod=prod*i` , `prod` also becomes `0` . Therefore , every time you get `0`;

Start loop with `i=1` .

*Note*  `int main()` -> `int main(void)`

Comment: thanks this is a silly mistake so i am going to remove the question im sorry for not trying to think